# How to deploy next.js frontend and separated express backend

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm developing an app that contains next.js as a frontend and separated backend server running on express. I'm wondering about production deploy and costs, I did some research but I'm not sure what's the best way to do it.

My folder structure is following. I have separated packages.json on the frontend and separated on the backend. Two apps also run on different port. Also I'm doing SSR on the frontend.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next.js already includes a server like express. [API Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) allow you to build a backend deployed along with the rest of the next application.

API Routes live in the `/pages/api` folder.

Comment: If you're deploying to Vercel I don't think it's possible to deploy a separate server along Next.js. Heroku on the other hand would allow this with some additional configuration/buildpacks.

Comment: I want to have frontend and backend on the same domain ex: api.domain.com and domain.com. Also How much would it cost to deploy the whole application on heroku and are they any alternatives?

Comment: Using Vercel the backend API would be under domain.com/api by default. Probably, you could also [get the subdomain to work](https://vercel.com/support/articles/pointing-subdomains-to-external-services). If you don't have a lot of traffic you can deploy it to heroku for free. However, there are tons of alternative hosting services to do what you're looking for. Would appreciate upvoting my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Think longterm. If in the future, it'll need to be scaled to accommodate traffic or have must separate domains then separating the backend from the frontend is the best way to go. This way each team can focus on their part without messing up the organization of the entire project. Also you have a clean interface for your clients (frontend, CLI and SDK). If not then having the backend in NextJS should be fine.